# I need to lock up text

Tags: html, css

4 image in row and I want to put text under the image.
I gave padding( 0 10px) to each image and gave justify-content:center, text align:center. My problem is the text start from left side padding. so text and image doesn't match center.

```css
.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-content img {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.main-content p {
  width: 263px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="main-image">
    <img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/microlink/s/5rgX4HJOW06kPEgGiqlpjIu0BWk_" width="263" height="174" alt="">
    <h3>cool bike</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
  </div>*4
```

Comment: remove width: 263px; from p

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you defined a width for your `p` element and so the text is being aligned to the middle of the `p` element. The width of your `p` element is shorter than your container and so that's why the text doesn't look aligned properly.

You have two solutions:

1. Simply set the width of the `p` element to inherit the width of the container:

```
.main-content p {
  width: 100%;
}
```

2. Or set the width of every element to be the same. So something like this:

```
.main-content {
  ...
  width: 263px;
}
.main-content img {
  ...
  width: 263px;
}
.main-content p {
  width: 263px;
}
```